# How to show all options of select element at once?

Tags: css, select, drop-down-menu

I have a select element. I need to show all options at once without dropping like this image[image]

How I could do this using css?

Comment: Do you want multi select?

Comment: no, it is one select only

Answer (score 1):

Ideally, if you found a way to limit the number of selectable items in `<select multiple> [...] </select>`, that would solve the problem, since `select multiple` shows all choices by default.

However, I've not been able to find a way to do this online, so we will have to do it in another way. This element has a `size` attribute, which represents the number of `option`s that will be shown. So, if you set this to the number of items in your `select`, you will be shown all of your items (just remember to set `overflow: auto;` in your CSS code to prevent scrollbars from being shown). If, however, the number of items is not fixed, you will have to change the `size` attribute via JavaScript. Here are some examples below.

```js
var dynamic = document.getElementById('dynamic');

dynamic.setAttribute('size', dynamic.childElementCount)
```

```css
.ns {
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<p>Normal selection:</p>
<select size="5">
  <option>Option 1</option>
  <option>Option 2</option>
  <option>Option 3</option>
  <option>Option 4</option>
  <option>Option 5</option>
<select>

<p>Selection without scrollbar:</p>
<select class="ns" size="5">
  <option>Option 1</option>
  <option>Option 2</option>
  <option>Option 3</option>
  <option>Option 4</option>
  <option>Option 5</option>
<select>

<p>Dynamic size selection:</p>
<select class="ns" id="dynamic">
  <option>Option 1</option>
  <option>Option 2</option>
  <option>Option 3</option>
  <option>Option 4</option>
  <option>Option 5</option>
  <option>Option 6</option>
  <option>Option 7</option>
  <option>Option 8</option>
<select>
```

Clearly, you can also add you own styles to the `select` element and the options